# Check if line is nullbytes

Tags: c++

I have a loop that reads line by line. In the loop I have a if block that check if the line is not a null byte. When a line comes with more than one null byte the if statement still returns true.

I need a way to check if a line is full of null bytes.

```
Block block = this->mMemblockDevice->readBlock(parent);
std::stringstream inputPath(block.toString());
std::string segment;
std::string contentNew = "";
while(std::getline(inputPath,segment)){
    if(segment != "\0"){ // If a / is last then a null byte
        contentNew += segment + "\n"; //Check size after every line
        std::cout << " Line Size: " << contentNew.size() << " Line: " << segment << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The reason why I have to check for null bytes is that I write to class that demands the size to be exactly 512 chars/bytes large so i do `content.resize(512, '\0');` Now I need to add chars to the string so I need to remove the null bytes so I can append the chars.

The std::cout in the loop outputs this:

```
 Line Size: 3 Line: 0/
 Line Size: 5 Line: 0
 Line Size: 513 Line:
```

Comment: why not just use content[i] after resize to set the characters? you can even use plain old memcpy to get the job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I simply just changed so I only check if the first char in the string is a null byte.

The working code looks like

```
while(std::getline(inputPath,segment)){
    if(segment[0] != '\0'){ // If a / is last then a null byte
        contentNew += segment + "\n"; //Check size after every line
        std::cout << " Line Size: " << contentNew.size() << " Line: " << segment << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) and search your entire string for null characters. If it does not find any then the function will return last.

```
if(std::find(std::begin(segment), std::end(segment), '\0') == std::end(segment))
{
    // string does not contain any null characters
}
```